# Gogs + Drone: Gogs webhook return 400 with Cannot find repository

Tags: drone.io, gogs

Drone CI has this repository in the drone home page, however, gogs webhook request reposonse 400 with cannot find the repository

Gogs webhook make a POST/hook request.

```
{
  "ref": "refs/heads/master",
  "before": "ae25bc66898ec377b5e94c39a4e9511a3640336a",
  "after": "ae25bc66898ec377b5e94c39a4e9511a3640336a",
  "compare_url": "",
  "commits": [
    {
      "id": "ae25bc66898ec377b5e94c39a4e9511a3640336a",
      "message": "[feat]: add ci drone.yml\n",
      "url": "http://gogs.site.com/root/Alertmanager-feishu-webhook/commit/ae25bc66898ec377b5e94c39a4e9511a3640336a",
      "author": {
        "name": "Bowser",
        "email": "bowser1704@icloud.com",
        "username": ""
      },
```

Response is:

```
{"message":"Cannot find repository"}
```

log is:

```
{"arch":"amd64","kernel":"","kind":"pipeline","level":"debug","msg":"manager: context canceled","os":"linux","time":"2020-09-27T03:15:10Z","type":"docker","variant":""}
{"arch":"amd64","kernel":"","kind":"pipeline","level":"debug","msg":"manager: context canceled","os":"linux","time":"2020-09-27T03:15:10Z","type":"docker","variant":""}
{"arch":"amd64","kernel":"","kind":"pipeline","level":"debug","msg":"manager: request queue item","os":"linux","time":"2020-09-27T03:15:20Z","type":"docker","variant":""}
{"arch":"amd64","kernel":"","kind":"pipeline","level":"debug","msg":"manager: request queue item","os":"linux","time":"2020-09-27T03:15:20Z","type":"docker","variant":""}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it by installing Drone on a dedicated instance. It seems like an obscure network problem.

[Drone doc](https://docs.drone.io/server/provider/gitea/)

> Please note we strongly recommend installing Drone on a dedicated instance. We do not recommend installing Drone and Gitea on the same instance using docker-compose due to network complications.